# XMLdocument invalid character error in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am converting Json into XMl document using below

```
var RawPostingXml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(CleanInvalidXmlChars((string)Message), "row");

            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            using (var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
            {
                RawPostingXml.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);    // GETTING ERROR HERE
                xmlTextWriter.Flush();
                Xml = stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
```

In order to remove the illegal character, I am using below code.

```
public static string CleanInvalidXmlChars(string text)
        {
            string re = @"[^\x07\x0A\x0D\x20-\xD7FF\xE000-\xFFFD\x10000-x10FFFF]";
            return Regex.Replace(text, re, "");
        }
```

But however i am getting the below error,

```
Exception - '', hexadecimal value 0x07, is an invalid character. Line 118, position 446.
```

**UPDATE:**

My input :

```
\u00a0 Our values and principles guide us forward each day. \u0007\u000e\u0004 \u3000\u000e\f \n \n \n \n \n\n\n\n
```

What went wrong in my code? Can anyone help me ?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to escape special characters such as <,> whenever they exist in attribute values and all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regular expressions, the metacharacter `[^ ]` will **negate** the character list. It will match what is **not** in your list.

You basically removed the entire XML, except for the incorrect characters.

Comment: When i do this string re = @"[\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\xD7FF\xE000-\xFFFD\x10000-x10FFFF]"; i am getting empty string :(

Comment: Probably because the range is to wide? `\x20` to `\xd7ff` seems to wipe out the entire printable ASCII set.

Comment: XML supports unicode, so there is no need to remove all these characters, only the non-printable ASCII ones.

Comment: What is the range ? can you please help me

Comment: `0x00` to `0x1f` are ASCII control characters.